# switch statement duplicate error

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a=5;
  switch(a)
  {
   case 1: ;
   case 2:;
   case 3+5:;
   case a:;

  }
}
```

Compiling this program, I get two errors:

- constant expression is required which is ok and expected.
- the second error says that duplicate `case`. Here `case a:` is duplicate with `case 1:`. Why second error is produced error? In `a` there is value of 5 and in case 1 it is 1. How 5 and 1 can conflict.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with: `switch( a ) /* ... */ case a /* ... */` ?

Comment: with `g++` I am getting second error `error: expected ‘:’ before ‘;’ token` , which compiler you are using ?

Comment: A case statments argument needs to be constant, so at least `case a:` is illegal.

Comment: The second warning appears because your compiler is free to diagnose what it wants--especially for syntactically invalid input.

Comment: OT: It should be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2):

When a compiler encounters an error, it attempts to recover, and continue. This means that it tries to change the code to something it thinks was meant (or nothing at all) and just continue right after the erronous piece of code.

Generally speaking, only the first compiler error is 100% correct, the following ones might just be "collateral damage" and have no real meaning at all.

Answer (score 2):

When you see multiple compiler errors, the only error that usually makes sense is the first one. The second error is often a "stray error" reported by your compiler in the process of recovering from the previous error. It is often the case with compilers that a single error gets them in a state in which they produce several other errors before recovering. The errors that they report is often different, too: for example, gcc compiler produces the "colon is required after `a`" error.

Back to your program, it is not possible to make it work with a variable, even if you declare it `const`, because C does not consider `a` from `const int a = 5` a compile-time constant. The only way to make it compile is to `#define a 5` with the preprocessor (you would need a colon after `a`, too).

You can make this program compile with a C++ compiler if you add `const` to the declaration of `a`. Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/JI4ZN7).

Answer (score 1):

```
c99 6.8.4.2
The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of
the case constant expressions in the same switch statement shall have the same value
after conversion. There may be at most one default label in a switch statement. (Any   
enclosed switch statement may have a default label or case constant expressions with  
values that duplicate case constant expressions in the enclosing switch statement.)
```

You can't have variables for the case it must be integer constants

```
case (integer Constant Expression) :
case a: this is not an integer constant expression
```

Answer (score 0):

case always take a constant value which is of the form int or char but you cannot compare a variable using this.

your second error is compiler dependent.so dont get stuck over there and carry on!!!

Answer (score -1):

you should always give integer constants as case value, that is why your switch is giving the  error at 'case a'. Replace it with a integer constant.

Comment: it is ok i got this error .but why another error duplicate case is there

Comment: If you comment the case a: you wont get any errors.

Comment: Two errors are as follow Case constant required and second one is Duplicate case:If i comment case 1 one error is produces that is error number 1 if i comment case a: no error will be produced.If i comment case 2: and case 3+5: then again two error will be produced.

Comment: In your case the error messages are produced because of the **case a:** line, even if you comment case 2: and case 3+5: you still have your **case a:** so the same error occur again.

Comment: but i am asking reason of Duplicate case error i know in case statement should be a constant but why there is duplicate error in this code

Comment: You can read the answers of rubenvb and dasblinkenlight for the answer

Comment: Not only integer values are allowed. Example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm

Comment: @adripanico: `'A'` is just a different way to write `65`.

Comment: 'A' can be whatever you want, but `switch` can be use with `char` and you states that it must be just with integers.

Comment: @adripanico characters are internally mapped to integers, characters are integer constants.